# object.splice is not removing the data from array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to fetch some data using Axios call and modify the data element by removing the matching element using object.splice(index,1)

but at the end result, I get all the elements the splice is not working,

I guess it might be something related to 'async and await' problem  but not sure how to solve it.

```js
getBeltDevicesList({ commit, dispatch,rootState}) {
  commit('common/SET_SCROLL_OVER_LOCK_STATE', false, {root: true });
  commit('common/SET_PENDING_STATE', true, { root: true});
  commit('SET_SELECTED_DEVICE_ID', null);
  const queryParams = {
    skip: 0,
    take: rootState.common.itemsOnPage,
    ...rootState.common.searchOptions,
  };
  return DataApiService
    .getDataElements(queryParams)
    .then(data => {
      data.forEach((dataElements, index, object) => {
        //alert(JSON.stringify(data))
        const { vId,typeId} = dataElements;
        if (vId !== null || typeId == 2) {
          // alert(typeId);//splice is not removing the elements 
          object.splice(index, 1);
        }
      });
      commit('SET_LIST', data);
      commit('common/SET_PENDING_STATE', false, {root: true});
      getDataElementsAssigning(data);
      setFormattedBootstrapDate(data);
      const selecteddataElement = rootState.common.pageMode === 'table' || !data.length ? null : data[0];
      dispatch('selectdataElement', selecteddataElement);


    });
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't delete from the array you're iterating over. You'll skip some elements.

Comment: thanks for the input what would be the alternative?

Comment: use `data = data.filter(...)`

Comment: this worked, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splice works, but splicing the current element will cause the next element to be skipped in the `forEach()` loop. Instead, you should use `filter()` to remove elements from the list.

```
data = data.filter(({vId,typeId}) => vId === null && typeId != 2);
```